# Replacing int to size_t in for statement with standard containers using regular expression

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have a really old, big x86 project, and now I need to port it to x64 architecture. 
Unfortunately, there are so many errors connected with mixing int/memsize types. For example:

```
std::vector<T> vec;
for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) // error, i must be size_t
{
}
```

So what I want is to replace all such strings with changing int to size_t.
Formally, the problem can be stated as follows:

Find string that matches following condition:

```
for(int [var name] = 0; [var name] < [container name].size(); [any expression])
```

Replace it with:

```
for(size_t [var name] = 0; [var name] < [container name].size(); [any expression])
```

I'm using visual studio 2008. I'm looking for most correct solution to this problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex for find what: `for[:b\n]*\([:b\n]*int[:b\n]+{:i}[:b\n]*=[:b\n]*0[:b\n]*;[:b\n]*{:i}[:b\n]*\<[:b\n]*{:i}\.size[:b\n]*\([:b\n]*\);[:b\n]*`

Replace with: `for(size_t \1 = 0; \2 < \3.size();` (note the ending space)

Comment: I need to replace only if .size() method is present in for statement.

Answer (score 0):

The 'most correct solution' is likely to involve using a parser that understands the C++ grammar, and then using that parser to rewrite your code after manipulating the parse tree.  The C++ grammar is not simple and for a task such as this, unless the project is exceptionally large you will most likely have to revert to using something that works in the majority of cases, rather than being technically correct.

The simplest way may be to write a set of search/replace regular expressions which do this work, with the regular expressions approximating the likely use cases, but as can be seen from the following example, the regex expressions are likely to be hard to read.

Here's a utility written in Python which approximates what you're trying to do.  It'll take a file on stdin or command line and produce converted text on stdout.  The regex is strict in matching the same identifier.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import fileinput
import sys
import re

regex = re.compile(
    r"""(?P<start>^\s*for\s*\(  # Leading for construct
      )(?P<type>int)(?P<remainder>\s+(?P<identifier>[A-Za-z_][0-9A-Za-z]*)  # int type followed by identifier
      \s*=\s*0\s*;  # Matches '= 0;'
      \s*(?P=identifier)\s*<\s*(?P<container>[A-Za-z_][0-9A-Za-z]*)\.size\(\); # ident < container.size();
      [^)]*\).*$)""",
      re.VERBOSE)

for line in fileinput.input():
    line = line.rstrip()
    match_object = regex.match(line)
    if match_object is not None:
        line = match_object.expand('\g<start>size_t\g<remainder>')
    print line
```